# Detect collision/colliding only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have an object that moves towards another object and physically collides with it, I want that collision/colliding event to happen only once. I tried using a `bool` but it didn't work as intended. It seems that I'm doing something wrong.

```
bool doDamage = true;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Target" && doDamage)
    {
        doDamage = false;
        // damage code
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Target")
    {
        doDamage = true;
    }
}
```

Edit:

I want the "damage code" to run only once, even if the 2 objects are still in contact. This script is only assigned to 1 object, not both.

Comment: do you mean that whole collision should happen only once and on second time this objects should behave like without colliders or you just want to control damage?

Comment: I want the whole collision to happen only once.

Comment: Prepare different layers for your game object. In physics settings uncheck the layer collision matrix for these two layers. Set same layer for both objects and change layer for one of them after the collision. They will not collide anymore. Also you may just change one of colliders into trigger after collision.

Comment: On the top of my mind, i do think OnCollisionEnter2D only gets called once, unless you collide in it again, later?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the easiest way to explain why your code is not working but I will try.

You have two GameObjects:

1. *GameObject A* with `doDamage` variable.
2. *GameObject B* with `doDamage` variable.

When *GameObject A* collides with *GameObject B*:

**A**.The `OnCollisionEnter2D` function is called on *GameObject A*. 
`if(other.gameObject.tag == "Target" && doDamage)` executes because `doDamage` is true.

**B**.The `doDamage` variable from *GameObject A* is then set to `false`.

**This does not affect the `doDamage` variable from *GameObject B*.**

Then

**C**.The `OnCollisionEnter2D` function is called on *GameObject B*. 
`if(other.gameObject.tag == "Target" && doDamage)` executes because `doDamage` is true.

**D**.The `doDamage` variable from *GameObject B* is then set to `false`.

Both your damage code will run because `doDamage` is always true in each `OnCollisionEnter2D` call. What you are currently doing is only affecting `doDamage` variable in each *individual* script.

**What you are  currently doing**:

Setting `doDamage` in the **local/this** script to `false` while also checking if **local/this** `doDamage` is set or not.

**What you need to do**:

Set `doDamage` in the **other** script to `false` but read the **local/this** `doDamage` to check if it is set or not.

This is what it should look like:

```
public class DamageStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool detectedBefore = false;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Target"))
        {
            //Exit if we have already done some damage
            if (detectedBefore)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Set the other detectedBefore variable to true
            DamageStatus dmStat = other.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageStatus>();
            if (dmStat)
            {
                dmStat.detectedBefore = true;
            }

            // Put damage/or code to run once below

        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Target")
        {
            //Reset on exit?
            detectedBefore = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't point this out before, but this script is assigned to only 1 gameobject, not both.

Comment: Then what do you mean by detect it once?

Comment: When the first object hit the second object, the collision stays active and the first object keeps doing damage. I want the damage code in the collision event to run only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a snippet of code once, run the code directly in the callback event that you want to trigger your code.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    DoSomeDamageTo(other.gameObject);
}
```

This should only trigger once upon collision.

If you want this to only ever happen once (e.g. if the object holding the script were to hit something again), you'll need a flag to say that the damage has already been done:

```
bool hasHitSomething = false;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (!hasHitSomething)
    {
        DoSomeDamageTo(other.gameObject);
        hasHitSomething = true;
    }
}
```

I suspect given the code you've shared, that either the objects are colliding multiple times in engine (very possible if they're solid and physics-controlled), leading to `OnCollisionEnter` being called multiple times. [`OnCollisionEnter` should only be called once per collision.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) If you are observing it being called multiple times, either you are actually observing multiple collisions, or you've found an obscure Unity bug. The former is much, *much* more likely.

Comment: The first part of your code is not different than what I'm doing.