# Play audio once when two identical objects collide

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have two objects (policeman) with same script attached that controls behaviour of these objects. When objects collide both have OnTriggerEnter working fine (makes them change into ragdoll and other stuff). In OnTriggerEnter there is OnPlaySound event that is fired for both objects. So when two objects collide I have two sounds played. What can I do to have this event fired for only one of them?

Shortened version of the script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    OnPlaysound(SoundType.SmallOoh);
    OnAddScore(1);
    StartCoroutine("Death");
    RagDoll();
}
```

**EDIT**

Solved it as Programmer suggested:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.getComponent<PoliceManScript>().soundPlayed == false)
    {
        soundPlayed = true;
        OnPlaysound(SoundType.SmallOoh);
    }
    OnAddScore(1);
    StartCoroutine("Death");
    RagDoll();
}
```

Comment: You could call other.RagDoll() instead of RagDoll(). Checking every time the event is triggered if your PoliceMan is a ragdoll already. If so, do not call the unwanted methods. Or have a public flag in collider which is set to true at collision. You could check this flag every time your method is triggered.

Comment: A duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41291480/3785314). You simply need a variable. Check that link on how to set the boolean variable and let me if there is a problem.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Problem is on OnPlaySound. I want the sound to be played once. RagDoll works ok, since both policeman have to fall after collision.

Comment: Is this reply to me or Michael? Use the @

Comment: I would recommend creating something like `SoundManager` and since it's a collision sound it will require 2 objects to hit each other. so inside the `SoundManager` you can just send 2 colliding objects 2 times ( if that makes sense ) first time from first object ( collider, colliding ) and second time ( colliding, collider ) and then check if they are matching. If so then play the sound.

Comment: @Programmer it was comment to Michael.

Comment: @m.rogalski - thanks for suggestion, Ill try Programmers suggestion first :)

Comment: Ok. You can just copy that logic directly and replace all the `OnCollisionEnterXXX` with `OnTriggerEnterXXX`. Just make sure you read and understand how it works.

Comment: Ok.Simple bool check works. Originally wanted to avoid other.getComponent<>() call but it doesn't look like big performance issue. thanks @Programmer!

Comment: Yeah, getComponent<>() is required in most OnCollisionEnter callback but it is not slow like people think. It should be a performance problem in your game. I will change the title of your question to reflect your problem more and to help others in the future.