# I want to generate only one event in the event of two object collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine

Each time a black bar touches an object, it displays information about the object.

When the black bar touches the A object, it displays the hidden `UI_A`.
And when the conflict is over, `UI_A` disappears.

The problem is that the black bars appear at the same time when both A and B objects touch `UI_A` and `UI_B` are appeared.

I want to have only one `UI` object appear when the black stick touches two objects at the same time.

What should I do?
Please help me!

===================================

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestPopUp : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject UI_A;
    public GameObject UI_B;
    public GameObject UI_C;

    private bool _IsTriggerEnter = false;



    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "A" && _IsTriggerEnter == false)
        {
            UI_A.SetActive(true);
            _IsTriggerEnter = true;
        }

        if (col.tag == "B" && _IsTriggerEnter == false)
        {
            UI_B.SetActive(true);
            _IsTriggerEnter = true;
        }

        if (col.tag == "C" && _IsTriggerEnter == false)
        {
            UI_C.SetActive(true);         
            _IsTriggerEnter = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "A")
        {
            UI_A.SetActive(false);
            _IsTriggerEnter = false;

        }

        if (col.tag == "B" )
        {
             UI_B.SetActive(false);
            _IsTriggerEnter = false;

        }

        if (col.tag == "C")
        {
            UI_C.SetActive(false);
            _IsTriggerEnter = false;

        }
    }
}
```

[Black bar and object A B C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vriNm.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect collision/colliding only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290547/detect-collision-colliding-only-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way is to use a flag variable, It means you can make a boolean variable(`UIisActive`)then when the first time the collision happens change its value so after the first collision the condition is wrong and it wont pass it till the boolean value changes back to its original value that happens in `OnTriggerExit`, I Also made some changes to the code and made a new method to stop the repeating code

```
void Start()
{
  bool UIisActive= false;
  bool _IsTriggerEnter = false;
}
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
     if(!UIisActive && _IsTriggerEnter == false){
        if (col.tag == "A")
            SAT(UI_A,true);
        else if (col.tag == "B")
             SAT(UI_B,true);
        else if (col.tag == "C")  
            SAT(UI_C,true);          
      }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "A")
            SAT(UI_A,false);
        else if (col.tag == "B" )
            SAT(UI_B,false);
        else if (col.tag == "C")
            SAT(UI_C,false);
    }

void SAT(GameObject go,bool state)
{
 go.SetActive(state); 
 _IsTriggerEnter = state;
 UIisActive=state
}
```