# Find both colliders involved in a collision on GameObject with Multiple colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

**To sum up the following:**
I want to find both colliders involved in a collision, from an OnTriggerEnter2D event. How can I do this?

I have two gameobjects. Both have a collider and a trigger.

On object A, it's surrounded by the trigger. On object B, the trigger only surrounds a certain section.

When the trigger of object A touches any collider, trigger or not, of object B: I want object B to lose health. And vice versa.

However, when the trigger of object A touches the collider (not trigger) of object B, both objects lose health.

I get this in the console

```
Object A hit Object B
Object B hit Object A
```

I came to the conclusion that the trigger of object A was calling the Ontrigger2d event on object B.

I think the best way to deal with this, is to find which collider 'found' the collision, and depending on that: ignore the collision..

How can I find which trigger 'found' the collision?

[Also posted on Unity Forums]

**EDIT:** Code

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Consumeable con = collision.GetComponentInParent<Consumable>();

    if (con != null && con.gameObject != gameObject)
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " hit " + con.gameObject.name);

        con.Damage(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have similar scripts on both object trying to damage the other trigger it came into contact with. Only one of them should apply the damage and the other should ignore the `OnTriggerEnter2D` callback. It'd help if you post the code you have at the moment.

Comment: Edited with code

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking. Is @SwiftingDuster correct with his comment? You want to apply damage to one gameobject only?

Comment: Here's a scenario: Object A touches Object B's collider with their trigger. Object B should be the only one to get the damage.

Comment: @WhoKnows then in Object b OnTrigger Function make it take damage.

Comment: In that case why not just remove this script for object A and only attach them to those that get damaged?

Comment: I think what you are refering to is Object b can have a collider, and a trigger, but whenever the trigger gets hit you want it to take damage, you dont want it to take damage if a "Projectile" trigger overlaps with Object b's Collider, or when it overlapse with its trigger?

Comment: Object B and object A have the same script to handle the triggers, the problem is, both of the scripts get called, regardless of if it's the one which touched the other with a trigger, or the other that was touched by that trigger

Comment: I need both objects to have that script.

Comment: What determines whether who takes damage in a collision? If you can find the unique trait of those that are exempt from damage you can check it for that condition before you decide if u want to apply the damage.

Comment: The one who takes damage should be the one who touched the other with the trigger

Comment: The OnTriggerEnter2D event is called on both objects, regardless of who touched who with what. I want to find a way to get who touched who with what.

Comment: With all these comment, you now understand that it doesn't make sense. `OnTriggerEnter2D` will be called on both objects when they touch. That's a fact. The question is: Which one do you want to apply damage to? What determines which one you want to apply damage to?

Comment: Alright, this is getting a bit complex, and I'm not sure everyone really understands what I want to achieve. To sum it up, I want to find both colliders involved in a collision

Comment: *"I want to find both colliders involved in a collision"* That's easy to do. Although I am sure that's not the only thing you want. What else after getting the two colliders involved in the collision?

Comment: Im fairly sure that's all I need, from there the rest is easy and I can do that myself. If you can tell me how to get the colliders involved that would be great. What I tried didn't work because I have two or more colliders on the game objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To sum it up, I want to find both colliders involved in a collision

There is a `gameObject` variable declared when your script inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. This variable refers to the GameObject this script is attached to. You can get one GameObject with that `gameObject` variable and the other one from the `Collider2D` argument in the `OnTriggerEnter` function.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    GameObject obj1 = this.gameObject;
    GameObject obj2 = collision.gameObject;

    Debug.Log("Triggered Obj1: :" + obj1.name);
    Debug.Log("Triggered obj2: :" + obj2.name);
}
```

**EDIT**:

> The objects are useless to me. I need the colliders. And no, I can't
>   use 'getcomponent' because they have more than one collider, and I
>   need only the ones in the collision

The colliders should be made child of the GameObject and the script must be attached to each child collider then what's in this answer should work.

---

If some reason you must do this without making the colliders child of that GameObject then use a boolean variable to detect the collision **once** only.

This is a modification of an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291480/3785314) post.

Have a local `Collider2D` variable named `theOtherCollider` to store the collision data first reported when `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called then have a another `boolean` variable named `detectedBefore` to determine if the `OnTriggerEnter2D` has been called before.

When `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called, check if the **local/this** version of that `boolean` variable is `false`. If it's not `true` then this is the first time `OnTriggerEnter2D` has been called. Use `GetComponent` to get the other script then set the `boolean` variable of the **other** script to `true`. At the-same time, also initialize the `theOtherCollider` variable on  the **other** script  with the `Collider2D` value from the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function.

Now, if `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called and the **local/this** version of that `boolean` variable is `true`, set it to `false` to reset it then obtain both colliders with `theOtherCollider` variable and the `Collider2D` variable from the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function.

This may be confusing but by looking the code, it is easier to understand.

Note:

`YOURSCRIPT` is the name of the script the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function is inside and that is attached to the Colliders. You must change it to whatever that script is named.

```
public bool detectedBefore = false;
public Collider2D theOtherCollider;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //Get both colliders then exit if we have already ran this code below
    if (detectedBefore)
    {
        //Reset
        detectedBefore = false;

        //Get both Colliders once below
        Collider2D col1 = theOtherCollider;
        Collider2D col2 = collision;

        Debug.Log("Triggered Obj1: " + col1.name);
        Debug.Log("Triggered obj2: " + col2.name);

        return; //EXIT the function
    }

    //Set the other detectedBefore variable to true then set get the first Collider
    YOURSCRIPT myScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<YOURSCRIPT>();
    if (myScript)
    {
        myScript.detectedBefore = true;
        myScript.theOtherCollider = collision;
    }

}
```

Comment: The objects are useless to me. I need the **colliders**. And no, I can't use 'getcomponent' because they have more than one collider, and I need only the ones in the collision

Comment: (After your edit) your solution works, however I was hoping that there was some way to find the collider she involved from the OnTriggerEnter2D event alone. I suppose I should just settle for what you said.

Comment: @WhoKnows Nope. There is another way to do it without that and I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achive this is to create a child gameobject to handle one of the colliders.

So for example you have a parent object that has a non-trigger collider, and a child with a trigger collider.

This way its easy to figure out wich colliders are involved in the collision.